# More Variables vs Multiple training routes in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing a simulation in *Tensorflow*, in which, during optimization, I need to add noise while substracting gradients. Suppose that I have 6 different types of noise, all of them are drawn from normal distribution with different standard deviations. During each iteration, I decide from what distribution the noise needs to be generated and then I apply this type of noise to all trainable variables.

**One way** to implement this, is to create variables of same shape as trainable variables and to assign to them different values of noise during training. For example, if I have some trainable variable `W`, I will create additional variable `W_noise`:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddev), name='W')
W_noise = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(W.shape, stddev=stddev1))
```

Then I will have an op for updating the noise variable, and during training I will choose by which standard deviation to generate it:

```
noise_op = tf.assign(W_noise, tf.random_normal(W_noise.shape, stddev=stddev2)
```

And the op for computing gradients (assume that I have a dictionary `noises` with trainable variables as 'keys' and noise variables as 'values', the `optimizer` is `GradientDescentOptimizer` and `var_list` is a list of trainable variables of tensor `loss`):

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, var_list)
op = tf.group([ tf.assign(v, v - learning_rate*g + noises[v]) 
            for g, v in grads_and_vars])
```

**Another way** that I thought of, is to create different routes of optimizations and pick through which to optimize during training:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, var_list)

    for i, stddev in zip(range(6), stddev_list):

        with tf.name_scope('Route_' + str(i)):
            train_route[i] = tf.group( [    tf.assign(v, v - learning_rate*g + tf.random_normal(v.shape, stddev=stddev)) 
            for g, v in grads_and_vars]     )
```

In tensorboard, it will look like this:
[image]

*In the picture, each route adds noise with different standard deviation while subtracting gradients and I can choose during training choose through which route to optimize.*

My thoughts and **questions** on this:

1. The first way has more ops to evaluate during each iteration (assign values to noise variables) and has `2 x (# of trainable_variables)` variables which consume more memory.
2. The second way creates larger amount of more complex ops (applying gradients) and since the number of types of noise is a parameter (and can be relatively large) it may consume more memory (how much more? is it something that I should worry about?)
3. What way is better (memory, speed)?
4. Is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would tell how you choose a route during training, it would help shaping an answer.

Comment: I'm simulating simultaneously on multiple graphs, so the noise depends on values of losses of all graphs. The graph with lowest loss gets the smallest amount of noise and so on. I didn't think it is relevant since my question is more general. You can assume that you have a function that given loss returns the route (or standard deviation)